Splitting Seurat object by sample layers
I have this seurat object:
An object of class Seurat 
16143 features across 29645 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (16143 features, 2000 variable features)
5 layers present: counts.control, counts.treated, data.control, data.treated, scale.data
2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, umap


I would like to split this by sample layer so I will have 2 separate Seurat objects, one of which such as:
An object of class Seurat 
15143 features across 19645 samples within 1 assay 
Active assay: RNA (16143 features, 2000 variable features)
**3 layers present: counts.control (or named just "counts"), data.control, scale.data**
2 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, umap


Do you know how to do that?
I tried:
obj.list <- SplitObject(seuratobject, split.by = 'orig.ident')
But it did not work.
